# Chrome, Firefox, and the mistery cache

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, internet, browser-cache

I am developing a website. It's just few lines of html. No phg, nothing fancy, very simple.
When I upload my file (Core ftp), the updates don't show on Chrome. I hard reloaded it 1000 times. F5, Ctrl F5, disable cache in dev tools, "Empty cache and hard reload"... you name it, I tried it. Then I gave up and decided to install Firefox and... I still get a cached version of the page!

I get the updated version in any other device (laptop, phone...) but there seems to be a cache on my desktop that I can't get rid of.

Any idea?

Using Windows 8. I even cleared all the users temp files.

Comment: There is something other than a cache problem going on here.  It sounds like you have two websites accessible.  Due to the offensive language I have issued a downvote.

Comment: @Chlain: Are you sure you're not using a proxy server or something? Also, it could be related to using the `www.` prefix on one device and not on the other. Depending on your web server's configuration it may make a difference.

Comment: @James: "www" does the trick. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Ramhound: Sorry for the language. I edited the post. You were on the right track too. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `www.` to the URL, per [James P's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/859547/chrome-firefox-and-the-mistery-cache/859556#comment1139446_859547), fixed it.

> ... Also, it could be related to using the `www.` prefix on one device and not on the other. Depending on your web server's configuration it may make a difference.